# Using Spring Web Reactive to distribute state "updates" to a large number of clients

Tags: spring, reactive-programming

Imagine a scenario of a Spring Web Reactive controller, with two methods in the style of:

```
@RequestMapping("/state/updatestream)
public Flux<State> getStateUpdates() {
    return stateService.updateStream();
}

@RequestMapping("/state/update") {
public Mono<Void> doUpdate(State state) {
    return stateService.doUpdate(state);
}
```

Where the stateService will push an update (through a server side event stream) to all clients when the doUpdate method is called by a client. An update will be a full state, not a delta. The order of states being pushed is important.

What would be a good way, or technology to implement the stateService in order to do this?

I have been messing around with creating a custom publisher to do this, but I have been running into issues with subscriptions (keeping the number of messages left sent in the publisher seems to be a pain, because the request method on the subscription object can be called concurrently, resulting at the latest State being pushed to the client concurrently... I only want the user to get the same state only one time). And even then it would not be able to scale very well, since I'd just be keeping the state in the application's memory in a stateful way.

Comment: do you mean you want to send a state to a client only once? Even if the client calls this metod at time T+n you want to send him all the states recorded so far, but not more than once. is tat correct?

Comment: I want to send him the latest state when he connects. Then when other clients (or he himself) updates the state, the new state should be sent to everyone who is still connected (and not cancelled).

Comment: of course it will be sent. what is the confusion here, sorry if i have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a decent, scalable way to do this from the stateService on.